# php - is include(file.php) the same as running it?

Tags: php, cron, include

I have a cron job set up in my `cron.php` file.

I also have a `function()` placed in that same file, which I want to use in other places.

Now the `cron.php` file has been set to run only one every 24 hours, meaning I don't want it to run multiply times.

somepage.php:

```
<?php
include_once("/cron.php");

echo someFunction(); //Function taken from cron.php

?>
```

Will the `cron.php` then run every time I load the `somepage.php` file?

Comment: Yes it will execute whatever is inside it the same way as when the cron job executes it

Comment: yes, because you include it.

Comment: Note: `/cron.php` will look for a `cron.php` in your root dir, which is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will.

When you want to cache the output from cron.php, you need to make an extra file, eg. 'cron-output.txt', and make cron.php put it's info there.
Ultimately you could use a database too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the code will run as if it exists within that file. Unencapsulated PHP code will be run as if it were inserted directly in the place of the `include` directive, and functions will only be run as called.

The prerequisite, however, is that the code must be wrapped in PHP open and close tags. From the [PHP docs on `include()`](http://php.net/include):

> When a file is included, parsing drops out of PHP mode and into HTML
> mode at the beginning of the target file, and resumes again at the
> end. For this reason, any code inside the target file which should be
> executed as PHP code must be enclosed within valid [PHP start and end
> tags.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php)